# Toggle CSS style based on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to toggle CSS style, based on ng-click event.

First time user click `ng-click` element the style will be applied, the second time click on `ng-click` element the CSS not changed as expected toggle.

Find working code below,

**HTML:**

```
<h1 ng-style="myObj" ng-click="change()">Welcome</h1>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.myObj = {
        "color": "white"
    }
    $scope.change = function () {
        $scope.myObj = {
            "color": "red"
        }
    }
});
```

I need to toggle CSS class based on `ng-click`.

Anyone guide me how to archive the same.

Comment: because your onchange event make it red and default is white use ng-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.myObj = {
    "color" : "blue"}
$scope.change=function()
{
  $scope.myObj.color == 'red' ? $scope.myObj.color = 'blue' : $scope.myObj.color = 'red';
 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"><h1 ng-style="myObj" ng-click="change()">Welcome</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) with a flag that'll be reverted on click.

```css
/* Default class */
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h1 ng-app ng-class="{'red': flag}" ng-click="flag=!flag">Welcome</h1>
```

By default the `flag` will be `undefined` and thus falsey, so the class will not be applied. When clicked, `flag = !flag` will set the flag to `true` and the `red` class will be applied. On next click, the `flag` will be set to `false` and the `red` class will be removed.